# Nesting setIntervals loops

Tags: javascript

How should two setInterval loops be nested?

On the outer loop (setInterval1), I wish to make a server request every 4 seconds, and then in the inner joop (setInterval2), I wish to do something ever 1 second.  After a few moments, my inner loop goes crazy, and if I attempt to clear it, it never triggers.

https://jsfiddle.net/y1f6nm6z/

```
var counter1 = 0;
var counter2 = 0;
var setInterval1 = setInterval(function() {
  //$.getJSON( '/getData.php', function(json) {
  console.log('counter1', counter1);
  counter1++;
  var setInterval2 = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('counter2', counter2);
    counter2++;
  }, 1000);
  //clearInterval(setInterval2);
  //});
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Do you mean to use setTimeout instead of setInterval? setTimeout will wait 4 seconds, then you can do a nested setInterval that will do something every second.  Nesting setIntervals will kickoff the second setInterval every 4 seconds.

Comment: _“How should two setInterval loops be nested?”_ – how about: “Not at all”? // Use _one_ loop that calls a function every second, and then inside that function decide based on a counter whether the current iteration is a multiple of 4 …

Comment: @user2263572  Maybe I do mean (or want) setTimeout.  Let me research.

Comment: @CBroe  Likely a better approach.  Let me rethink things.

Comment: @user1032531 it really looks like that's what you need because you are clearing the interval (at least the intention is there with the comment) immediately. However, clearing it right after it's set means it will never fire.

Comment: @user2263572  Yea, setTimeout probably is better for my approach as it doesn't not need to occur at the exact time intervals.

Comment: @CBroe  I definitely think you are correct.  When would one chose setInterval over setTimeout when doing so?

Comment: @user1032531 this is opinion based. But I would never use `setInterval` except for some debugging purpose, and always would prefer `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not nest setIntervals** (except if you clear them, maybe)

This is what happens when you do so:

```
setInterval1
     ├────> function1 ────> setInterval2
     │                           ├────> function2
     │                           ├────────> function2
     │                           ├────────────> function2
     │                           ⋮
     ├────────> function1 ────> setInterval2
     │                               ├────> function2
     │                               ├────────> function2
     │                               ├────────────> function2
     │                               ⋮
     ├────────────> function1 ────> setInterval2
     │                                   ├────> function2
     │                                   ├────────> function2
     │                                   ├────────────> function2
     │                                   ⋮
     ├────────────────>  …
     ⋮
```

I recommend `setTimeout` instead:

```js
var counter1 = 0;
var counter2 = 0;
(function timeout1() {
  console.log('counter1', counter1);
  counter1++;
  var i = 0;
  (function timeout2() {
    console.log('counter2', counter2);
    counter2++;
    ++i;
    setTimeout(i < 4 ? timeout2 : timeout1, 1000);
  })();
})();
```

Even if you nest them, they are usually less problematic than `setInterval`. But use some conditional to make sure you only call `setTimeout` when necessary.

```js
var counter1 = 0;
var counter2 = 0;
(function timeout1() {
  console.log('counter1', counter1);
  counter1++;
  var i = 0;
  (function timeout2() {
    console.log('counter2', counter2);
    counter2++;
    ++i;
    if(i < 4) setTimeout(timeout2, 1000);
  })();
  setTimeout(timeout1, 4000);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks Oriol, Yea, I witnessed that exponential growth!  Any thoughts on using nested timeouts versus a single timeout loop with logic to determine the period?

Comment: @user1032531 You can nest them, but make sure the inner function is only called 4 times per each outer call.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new interval every 4 seconds. Don't nest `setInterval`. Maybe what you really want is `setTimeout`?